# Each group without parent

Tags: jquery

I have few groups of links, for example:

```
<a href="http://google.com/b">http://google.com/b</a>
<a href="http://google.com/a">http://google.com/a</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/g">http://stackoverflow.com/g</a>
<a href="http://google.com/c">http://google.com/c</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a">http://stackoverflow.com/a</a>
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/c">http://en.wikipedia.org/c</a>
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/a">http://en.wikipedia.org/a</a>
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/b">http://en.wikipedia.org/b</a>
```

I need to sort google.com links and wikipedia.org links, and keep their position, but my question is not about sorting. My question about iteration in groups of elements. For my example it would be:

```
$("a[href*='google.com'], a[href*='en.wikipedia.org']").each(function(){

  // I need in $(this) google.com links in first iteration, and wikipedia.org links in second 

});
```

Is there any native way to do that?

PS it is imposible to wrap() and I don't want to do any [additional functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).

Comment: And what do you want the HTML to look like *after* this function runs?

Comment: I'm confused by first and second iteration. Won't it iterate over all? If you want to iterate over all google links first, then all wikipedia links second, perhaps this will work: `$("a[href*='google.com']").add( "a[href*='en.wikipedia.org']").each etc.` I haven't tried it.

Comment: @Shredder yes. I want to know is js or jquery has native way to do iterations with groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to process them in groups per domain, you can iterate the domains and find relevant elements:

```
$.each(['google.com', 'en.wikipedia.org'], function (_, domain) {
    var links = $('a[href*="' + domain + '"]');

    // 1st round will have `google.com` links, 2nd `en.wikipedia.org`
});
```

Then you can use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) to wrap each collection in a single element:

```
links.wrapAll('<div>');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AmYCk/

```
<div>
    <a href="http://google.com/b">http://google.com/b</a>
    <a href="http://google.com/a">http://google.com/a</a>
    <a href="http://google.com/c">http://google.com/c</a>
</div>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/g">http://stackoverflow.com/g</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a">http://stackoverflow.com/a</a>

<div>
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/c">http://en.wikipedia.org/c</a>
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/a">http://en.wikipedia.org/a</a>
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/b">http://en.wikipedia.org/b</a>
</div>
```

Comment: lol smart. This [http://jsfiddle.net/AmYCk/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/AmYCk/1/) exacly what I need, but unfortunately it's more like hackish not native.

Comment: @ancap Well, JavaScript doesn't have a native "*group by*" function or method. jQuery doesn't define one either since its focus is generally with flat collection of elements. You can find one in either [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) or [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following instead:

```
$('a[href*="google.com"]').add('a[href*="en.wikipedia.org"]').each(...);
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2xKk/) for an example.

Comment: It iterate each link [http://jsfiddle.net/Z5rGf/](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5rGf/). Not groups of google.com and wikipedia links.

Comment: Then you probably want to use Jonathan Lonowski's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Improved version

```
$([$("a"), $("span")]).each(function(){
  console.log($(this).length);
});
```

[**`jsbin.com`**](http://jsbin.com/eCIfiDa/20/edit?html,js,console)